# Authenticate GET request from html extensions in AEM

Tags: java, servlets, aem

Good day,

When a user hit specific url with an extension on html, I want to validate if user has logged in. If the user is not logged in, I want to redirect them to my custom login page (this part is done). Else, I want to do nothing - meaning the current page that they are on, should continue being displayed.

I want this to meet client requirements (the default AEM login page should stay as is.

Scenario

The page is /content/mysite/page.html

If I am not logged in, I should be redirected to /content/mysite/login.html

If I am logged in, I should still see this page : /content/mysite/page.html

Now, my problem comes when I am logged in. Instead of seeing content of the page : /content/mysite/page.html, there page is simply blank. There are no contents to be displayed.

Maybe I do not get the concepts of servlets or I do not know how to handle this kind of problem.

Please help resolve this or suggest another route to handle this

**Here is my the code I have so far:**

```
package com.company.patientsportal.core.auth;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Map;

import javax.jcr.Repository;
import javax.jcr.Session;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;

import org.apache.felix.scr.annotations.Activate;
import org.apache.felix.scr.annotations.Properties;
import org.apache.felix.scr.annotations.Property;
import org.apache.felix.scr.annotations.Reference;
import org.apache.felix.scr.annotations.Service;
import org.apache.felix.scr.annotations.sling.SlingServlet;
import org.apache.sling.api.SlingHttpServletRequest;
import org.apache.sling.api.SlingHttpServletResponse;
import org.apache.sling.api.resource.ResourceResolver;
import org.apache.sling.api.servlets.SlingAllMethodsServlet;
import org.apache.sling.engine.SlingRequestProcessor;

@Service
@SlingServlet(resourceTypes={"patientsportal/components/structure/page"},    selectors="html", methods = "GET", metatype=true, description="My Authentication  Verifier")
@Properties
(
    {
        @Property(name="login.form", description="The form on which the user  to enter authentication credentials.", value="")
    }
)
public class CheckAuthentication extends SlingAllMethodsServlet
{
/**
 * 
 */
private static final long serialVersionUID = 8552708551560032677L;

private Map<String, Object> redirects;


@Reference
private Repository repository;

@Reference
private SlingRequestProcessor requestProcessor;

@Override
protected void doGet(SlingHttpServletRequest request, SlingHttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException
{
    ResourceResolver resolver = request.getResourceResolver();

    Session session = resolver.adaptTo(Session.class);

    String userId = session.getUserID();

    String url = request.getRequestPathInfo().getResourcePath();
    url = url.substring(0, url.lastIndexOf("/")) + ".html";

    if (String.valueOf(userId) == null || (String.valueOf(userId) != null ? String.valueOf(userId).equals("anonymous") : false))
    {
        String loginForm = getLoginForm("login.form");

        if (loginForm != null)
        {
            response.sendRedirect(loginForm + "?url=" + url);
        }
        else
        {
            response.sendRedirect("/content/patientsportal/login.html?url=" + url);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        //Do nothing or something in the else
        //So far, do nothing does not work. It returns blank page even if I do not include the else part
    }
}

private String getLoginForm(String loginForm)
{
    if (redirects != null)
    {
        loginForm = (String) redirects.get(loginForm);
        return loginForm;
    }
    return null;
}

@Activate
protected void activate(Map<String, Object> properties)
{
    redirects = properties;
}
}
```

Comment: any specific reason for not going with the OOTB Closed User Group functionality?

Comment: Hi Ameesh, thank you so much for replying. I am not sure if using CUP will allow me to use my own defined login page. Note: I am fairly junior to AEM. How do you reckon this works for my solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ideal way of implementing login functionality is to either use the OOTB AEM authentication handler or implement Sling `AuthenticationHandler` and extending `DefaultAuthenticationFeedbackHandler`. You can find the code references to implement in lot of blogs -

- [acs-aem-samples](https://github.com/Adobe-Consulting-Services/acs-aem-samples/blob/master/bundle/src/main/java/com/adobe/acs/samples/authentication/impl/SampleLoginHookAuthenticationHandler.java)
- [How to Create Custom Authentication Handler in CQ](http://www.wemblog.com/2013/03/how-to-create-custom-authentication.html)

After you have implemented this and have **created/configured your own login page /form**, you need to setup CUG on the pages that are to be exposed only to a logged in user. The details around it are available in AEM documentation [here](https://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/aem/6-2/administer/security/cug.html)

Comment: Hi Ameesh, thank you for responding once again. I have just browsed through the AEM documentation ling about CUP that you have provided.

After seeing this line :

"6. Specify the Login Page that members of the group will use; for example:
    /content/geometrixx/en/toolbar/login.html 
This is optional, if left blank the standard login page will be used."

I will be marking this as a solution. Thanks for your help and I'll let you know how this goes. Thanks again